# Работа с файлами в си. Переписать данные из одного файла в другой так чтобы строки шли в обратном порядке

Tags: c

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить задачу. Дан текстовый файл. Необходимо создать новый файл и переписать из исходного файла данные так чтобы строки шли в обратном порядке.

Answer (score 2):

Безусловно, mmap-нуть файл это хороший вариант, но если от вас ждут другого (продемонстрировать умение работать с файлами), то придется действительно читать файл "сзаду наперед".

Для этого  у нас все есть (читаем [man fseek](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fseek.3.html)) и можно написать код
(который, наверное, (я не поверял) будет работать не только в *nix-ах)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

// returns EOF for call at the beginning of the FILE
int
get_prev_char (FILE *f)
{
  int r = fseek(f, -1L, SEEK_CUR);
  if (r == -1)
    return EOF;
  int c = fgetc(f);
  fseek(f, -1L, SEEK_CUR);
  
  return c;
}


int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  if (!av[1]) {
    puts("no input file name");
    return 1;
  }

  
  FILE *in = fopen(av[1], "r");
  if (!in) {
    perror(av[1]);
    return 1;
  }

  FILE *out = stdout;
  if (av[2]) {
    if (!(out = fopen(av[2], "w"))) {
      perror(av[2]);
      return 1;
    }
  }

  fseek(in, 0, SEEK_END);
  
  for (int l = 0, i = 0, c = 0; c != EOF; l++, i = 0) {
    char str[LINE_MAX + 1];

    while ((c = get_prev_char(in)) != EOF) {
      if (c != '\n' && i < LINE_MAX)
        str[i++] = c;
      else
        break;
    }
    if (l == 0 && i == 0)
      continue;
    //    reverse(str, i);
    for (int j = 0, k = i - 1; j < k; j++, k--) {
      int t = str[j];
      str[j] = str[k];
      str[k] = t;
    }
    str[i++] = 0;

    fprintf(out, "%s\n", str);
  }
  
  return out != stdout ? puts("End") == EOF : 0;
}
```

Компилируем и проверяем

```
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$ cat 1
line 1
   line 2
lline 3
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$ gcc ttt.c && ./a.out 1 2
End
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$ cat 2
lline 3
   line 2
line 1
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$
```

Comment: Да или так) все варианты хороши, но  что будет если в файле 1 строка больше чем 2048 (ну или что там в лимитах)? Я про строку  fprintf(out, "%s\n", str); я думаю там появится лишний newline а если и это убрать - будет тоже что-то не ожидаемое

Comment: @Oh-Ben-Ben, да, длинные строки будут резаться (выводиться как несколько). Просто решил не  усложнять пример, выстраивая (realloc-ом) строку в динамической памяти (оставим это студенту в качестве упражнения -))

Answer (score 0):

1. Прочитать файл построчно в массив строк.
2. Записать в новый файл, но читать массив не с 0 до n, а с n до 0.
3. Не забыть закрыть оба файла.

Comment: что то как-то не очень эффективно ) зачем дампить файл в память? надо просто замапить файл и идти по нему с конца

Comment: такая идея была, но я надеялся, что есть функция, которая перенесет указатель на нужную строку

Answer (score 0):

Не нужно считывать весь файл в память - есть более эффективные методы работы с файлами (представьте себе, что у вас файл больше чем RAM?)

Логика довольно простая :

1. Надо отобразить файл в память (mmap - https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html)
2. Идти по этой памяти с конца и искать \n (символы новых строк) сохраняя старую позицию успешного поиска
3. В случае нахождения нью лайна - писать в дескриптор с позиции до старой позиции

вот пример кода (тут вместо другого файла все пишется в stdout)

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <err.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct stat s;
    const char *file_name = "data";
    int fd = open(file_name, O_RDONLY);

    int status = fstat(fd, &s);
    if (status != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "No such file (%d)\n", status);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    size_t size = s.st_size;
    fprintf(stdout, "file size: %d\n", size);
    char *ptr = (char *)mmap(0, size, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
    if (!ptr)
    {
        close(fd);
        fprintf(stderr, "mmap error\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "mmap ret %d(%s)\n", errno, strerror(errno));
    fprintf(stderr, "Shared Mem Address: %p [0..%lu]\n", ptr, size - 1);

    size_t last = size;

    for (int i = size; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        if ((ptr[i] == '\n' || !i) && last - i)
        {
            write(1, !i ? &ptr[i] : &ptr[i + 1], last - i);
            last = i;
        }
    }

    munmap(ptr, size);
    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Круто, но минус за непереносимость кода.

Comment: @ori а где в вопросе требование о переносимости ?